# Probability density function using histogram data

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I plot `numpy.ndarray` (length 1400) using Matplotlib. I want to detect the "peaks" and create a function such that it is 0.1 when "not a peak" and the y-value of the peak when a peak.

Example chart:

[image]

Comment: Define "peak". Is `y[i]` a peak if `y[i] > max(y[i-1], y[i+1])`?

Comment: @Eric Not all of them-- a shorter range of them, the bigger ones only.

Comment: I agree with Eric: first make a clear definition of your problem/question. If e.g. peak is everything larger than 15, you can write the solution as a one-liner in Python. If you need some fancy peak-detection-algorithm, things can get a lot more complicated.

Comment: @Bart Nothing fancy. But if you think the definition Eric mentioned-- it is going to capture too many "peaks". I guess it is quite intuitive what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply [DetectPeaks](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/demotu/BMC/blob/master/notebooks/DetectPeaks.ipynb) to your data. Calculate the second derivative and decide regarding your mpd, mph settings.

```
first_derivative = np.gradient(data)
second_derivative = np.gradient(first_derivative)
ind = detect_peaks(second_derivative, mpd=20,mph=0, show=True)
print(ind)
```

Then fill your arrays with either 0 or maximums---

```
arr = []

for i in range(0,len(n_test)):
    for j in ind:
        if i == j:
            arr.append(n_test[i])
    arr.append(0)


plt.plot(arr)
```

Finally, check out other peak detection options -- [peak detection overview](https://blog.ytotech.com/2015/11/01/findpeaks-in-python/)